# Window resizing issue

Tags: javascript

I have an application that open's some dynamic popup either using `window.open()` or using `window.showModalDialog()` the content of jsp's being popped up varies and is dynamic in nature, can i adjust the page size on addition of new fields dynamically?

this toggle Message is called on change of a radio button

`toggleMessage(element){
 var versionNoCreated; 
if(element.value == 'yes') 
{
 window.dialogWidth='20px'; 
//window.resizeTo(20,20); 
}
 else 
{
 window.dialogWidth='200px'; 
//window.resizeTo(200,200);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

`window.resizeTo(x,y)` or `window.resizeBy(incrementX,incrementY)`

for the window open and

`window.dialogWidth='x px';` and `window.dialogHeight='y px';`

for the modal dialog

Comment: its working once only... if i have to toggle betwween to sizes its not working i tried it like  function toggleMessage(element){
  var versionNoCreated;
  if(element.value == 'yes')
  {
   window.dialogWidth='20px';
   //window.resizeTo(20,20);
  }
  else
  {
   window.dialogWidth='200px';
   //window.resizeTo(200,200);
  }
  }

Comment: HOW do you toggle. And please just update your question instead of adding comments

Comment: Can you try  `toggleMessage(element){ var versionNoCreated; if(element.value == 'yes') { window.dialogWidth='20px'; /*window.resizeTo(20,20);*/ } else { window.dialogWidth='200px'; /*window.resizeTo(200,200);*/ } }`